# How to match string of two different dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, match

How to match body text on different data frames? I have coded using python, but for some reason, the results in the Match column are all False. Even though there is a matching text content between data frame 1 and data frame 2.

Here is my code :

```
# List of search keywords
search_term = ["Gempa AND #gempa cianjur AND #gempa maluku", 
               "Sambo AND #ferdy sambo AND #brigadir j",
               "Lukas Enembe AND #lukas enembe tersangka AND #gubernur papua",
               "Puan Maharani AND #pdip AND #pilpres2024",
               "Putri Candrawathi AND #LPSK AND #brigadir yosua",
               "Resesi AND #resesi AND #APBD DKI",
               "IKN AND #ikn AND #ibu kota nusantara",
               "Piala AFF 2022 AND #piala aff 2022 AND #pssi",
               "Pemilu 2024 AND #partai politik pemilu 2024",
               "BMKG AND #BMKG",
               "Kripto AND #kripto AND #investasi",
               "Ekonomi AND #ekonomi indonesia AND #jokowi",
               "Elon Musk AND #elon musk",
               "Jokowi AND #Jokowi",
               "Puan AND #puan",
               "Ganjar Pranowo AND #Ganjar Pranowo AND #Pilpres 2024"]

# Calling DataFrame constructor on list
# with indices and columns specified
searc_term_df = pd.DataFrame(search_term,columns =['Search Term'])
searc_term_df['Search Term'] = searc_term_df['Search Term'].str.replace('AND','')
searc_term_df['Search Term'] = searc_term_df['Search Term'].str.replace('#','')

# Tokenize a sentence into a piece of words
def tokenize_data(tweet):
   return word_tokenize(tweet)
searc_term_df['Search Term'] = searc_term_df['Search Term'].apply(tokenize_data)

# Remove brackets from string
searc_term_df['Search Term'] = searc_term_df.astype(str).apply(lambda col:col.str.strip('[]'))
# Remove single quotes from string
searc_term_df['Search Term'] = searc_term_df['Search Term'].str.replace('\'', '')
searc_term_df
```

The output is like this :

[image]

I want to match it with data frame 2, which results in data frame 2 below :
[image]

Here is the code to match it, but the results I get are all False :

```
df_all['Match'] = df_all['Text'].isin(searc_term_df['Search Term'])
```

Here is the wrong output :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea I had to solve this problem uses the bag of words idea with [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) from scikit-learn.

Initially I created a dataset to simulate your `df_all['Text']`, adding some words present in `searc_term_df` that you definded.

```py
test_text = [
    "Lorem ipsum gempa sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum Puan sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum Jokowi sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum Elon Musk amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum Pranowo sit amet.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor, 2024 amet.",
]

df_all = pd.DataFrame(data=test_text, columns=["text"])
```

And then I instantiated the Bag of Words (`CountVectorizer()`) model.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np

# here I removed the commas from the search terms because they were also being
# interpreted as a match, but you can come up with another fancy pre-processing strategy
search_terms = searc_term_df["Search Term"].replace({",": ""}, regex=True)

# fits the model to your text data
vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit(df_all["text"])

# creates a bag of words (BoW)
bow_text = vectorizer.transform(df_all["text"]).toarray()

# creates a bag of words of the search terms too
bow_search_terms = vectorizer.transform(search_terms).toarray()

# creates a sparse matrix that corresponds to the number of matches
# for each search term. A sum equal to 0 means there is no match.
is_a_match = (np.dot(bow_text, bow_search_terms.transpose()).sum(axis=1) != 0)
df_all["match"] = is_a_match

df_all
```

Here's the output

```
    text                            match
0   Lorem ipsum gempa sit amet.      True
1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.     False
2   Lorem ipsum Puan sit amet.       True
3   Lorem ipsum Jokowi sit amet.     True
4   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.     False
5   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.     False
6   Lorem ipsum Elon Musk amet.      True
7   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.     False
8   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.     False
9   Lorem ipsum Pranowo sit amet.    True
10  Lorem ipsum dolor, 2024 amet.    True
```